# HTTPS requests and multi-threading

Tags: java, url, connection, connection-pooling

Is Java's [`URL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class a thread-safe, in particular [`URL.openConnection()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection())?

In my application, I make tens of concurrent HTTPS connections a second to the same URL, and I would like to maximize object reuse.  Yet, it's not clear from the documentation what can be reused.

EDIT: I'm open to using a different library if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My standard response about HTTP and java is to recommend [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org). It supports HTTP 1.1, so you can keep those connections open for reuse after you've had a successful HTTP request/response with the server.

It has built-in support for connection pooling and the documentation [describes](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e629) how to use it in a multithreaded context.

Comment: +1 for the multithreaded HttpClient choice.  You'll save a lot of hairpulling.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's thread-safe. I use it in many threads and haven't found any issues.

The Sun's default handler also supports keep-alive by default so multiple threads may share the same connection. You have to be careful to read all responses (including ErrorStream). Otherwise, the next request will start in a bad state.

Answer (score 0):

URL.openConnection will make a HttpsURLConnection object, which is a subclass of HttpURLConnection.  The [docs for HttpURLConnection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) state that it may use a single underlying connection to the server to statisfy multiple requests.  I'm assuming this is sharing ala HTTP 1.1.

So you will get a new HttpsURLConnection object with each URL.openConnection call, but you won't get lots of network connections.